# pip broken, can't use most of pip commands (on windows)

Tags: python-3.x, pip

So I was working with python, coding and installing packages, everything was going ok, but then everything with pip stoped working, and every times the cmd prompt me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 69, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 91, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\list.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import IndexGroupCommand
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "c:\python39\lib\cgi.py", line 41, in <module>
    import html
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html'
```

I never run into those kind of errors.
BTW pip -V is working, and when I try to run a programme using python with the already installed package and it still works fine.

I tried to reinstall python partially after restarting my pc, and nothing with pip has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, here is what I have done, and more context that may help you understand where the  problem was coming from :

So I was doing an gui app using pyqt5 and I was having trouble with PySide2, the first error of this kind was when I tried to install it with pip (pip install PySide2). I don't know where the error came from, but if you encounter this after in a similar situation, there way be a problem with that.

what I have done to fix it was not re-installing python or pip but using the repair "tool" when installing the version of python already installed.

Comment: I will be able to accept my answer in 2 days